# Proof correction for $X\space\times\space Y \subseteq Y\space\times\space Z$, then $X\subseteq Z$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that if $X\space\times\space Y \subseteq Y\space\times\space Z$, then $X\subseteq Z$.

I approached this question in the following way.

$X\space\times\space Y \subseteq (Y\space\times\space X) \space\cup\space(Y\space\times\space Z')$

$X\space\times\space Y \subseteq Y\space\times\space(X\space\cup\space Z')$

$X\subseteq(X\space\cup\space Z')$

$X\subseteq Z$

I realise that my reasoning here is flawed as  the Cartesian product of two sets are not commutative. However, I'm not sure how I would otherwise approach this problem.

Comment: The statement is not true without additional hypotheses.

Comment: @EricWofsey Are you sure?  Is it not true that $A \times B \subseteq A \times C \implies B \subseteq C,$ and that $A \times B \subseteq D \times B \implies A \subseteq D$?  Can't this approach be used to show that $X \subseteq Y \subseteq Z$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Re previous comment, does $\{X \times Y \subseteq Y \times Z\}$ imply that $\{X \times Y \subseteq X \times Z\}$?  I am on shaky ground here, and could easily be mistaken.  It would be interesting to construct a counter example, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the sets are nonempty, $X\times Y\subseteq Y\times Z$ if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq Z$, and so by transitivity, we have $X\subseteq Z$. (Choose elements to verify the first statements, if you wish.)

However, there is a loophole. Suppose $Y=\emptyset$. Then $X\times\emptyset = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset\times Z = \emptyset$, and yet $X$ and $Z$ can be totally arbitrary.